# How do you solve this question without cross multiplying?

Tags: inequality

How do you solve this question without cross multiplying?

$$\Big| \frac{2}{x-4}\Big|>1 , \quad x \neq 4 ?$$

Comment: Since you're new, I'd like to give you some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are**. That way, people won't tell you stuff you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to solve it without cross multiplying? You could just multiply both sides by $(x-4)$, which is superficially distinct from cross multiplying, but fundamentally the same.

Comment: We will ultimately have to "cross-multiply" by $2$.

Comment: No, we don't have to.

Comment: Why without cross multiplying? That seems to be the simplest way to go by.

Comment: This a very simple inequality with no problem with 'cross-multiplying', but it is a good advice to students to avoid or be very careful with multiplication in inequalities. In general the sign may change, and one has to be studying the cases in which the factor is positive or negative. For example when solving inequalities of the form $R(x)\leq Q(x)$, for $R$ and $Q$ rational, in general it tends to be more convenient to not 'cross-multiply'. That said, this is not a dogma. Here 'cross-multiplication' is very easy.

Comment: I think one of the very first warnings/explanations high schools (or even junior high school) students receive when they begin dealing with absolute value and inequalities is precisely to be pretty careful when multiplying/dividing by negative quantities. This could be an exercise to develop in this direction, yet I can't see how you @RGB could know that since the OP hasn't said half a thing...

Comment: What are you claiming I know that I am not supposed to know? I am just saying that asking to solve an inequality without cross-multiplying is valid question, and explaining why. Perhaps the OP knows how to solve it multiplying but was told that every inequality can be solved without multiplying and didn't how to do this one in particular. The questions of the beginners should be taken more seriously and not with that snobbism, sometimes they carry some wisdom  in them.

Answer (score 3):

For $x-4\geq0$ the inequality is equivalent to $\frac{2}{x-4}>1$. From this we get $\frac{6-x}{x-4}>0$, which is equivalent to $6-x>0$, in the case we are studying. So we get the solutions $6>x\geq4$.

Now you do the case $x-4<0$.